# Load flat file into a predetermined table

Tags: sql-server, import, csv

#### Scenario

1. Table created

   [image]
2. Data in flat file loaded to the table but with errors. please advise how to fix it

   (a) 'address' is split to 3 columns causing mismatch between the source and destination

   [image]

   (b) 3 Nulls in the 'B_Date' column due to different format. Do I need to massage the raw file before load into the Microsoft SQL or what is the SQL formula?

#### raw file

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think address is being split into three columns? Based on your screenshot column 5 is being mapped to address and 6 and 7 aren’t being mapped to anything.

Can you please share the full error messages? Also does your file have headers, I presume not based on your screenshot. Try adding headers to the flat file and letting the wizard create the destination table for you.